Help with understanding needed rebar
I've received a structural engineer report where the engineer has defined the dimensions of the required padding. It's the padding that a steel column post will be bolted into. I noticed he's put some spec for concrete reinforcement using rebar. I'm just wondering, from the design below how do I understand the required rebar needed?
The only thing I can understand is that U-Bars are required but can I not use the ordinary mesh cages that is normally used for reinforcing concrete?


Are you querying the engineer's competence? If so, why did you employ him/her in the first place? Why not accept the solution?

Those U bars on the bottom of the foundation are specified in both perpendicular directions. They will form a mesh on the bottom.
You can't use ordinary mesh because the required amount of steel is much larger in one direction than the other (due to geometry and loads). If there was mesh that covered the Z-Z requirement, you'd be under-using the reinforcement on the X-X direction.
That's all there is to it.
